# Display Near by leads Contacts Accounts on visualforce google map?

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration, google-map

Visualforce Page:

```
 <apex:page controller="mapController" tabStyle="Contact" action="{!find}" id="page">
        <head>
            <style>
                div #map_canvas { height: 400px; }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        </head>
        <apex:sectionHeader subtitle="Address full text search + Google Maps integration" />
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:form id="form">
            <apex:pageBlock id="searchBlock">
                <apex:inputText value="{!searchText}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!find}"/>
                <p>Examples: <a href="/apex/{!$CurrentPage.Name}?q=USA">"USA"</a>, "Singapore", "Uni", "(336) 222-7000". If it works in the global search box, it will work here.</p>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlock title="Found {!sobjlst.size} Contact(s)..." rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(contacts)) && contacts.size > 0}" id="resultsBlock">
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Clear cached locations" title="Click if you want to set 'null' as geolocation info for all these contacts" action="{!clearGeocodedData}" />
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:outputText value="{!ContactsJson}"></apex:outputText>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" id="contacts">
                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Contact.fields.Name.label}">
                        <apex:outputLink value="../{!c.Id}">{!c.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Address">
                        {!c.MailingStreet} {!c.MailingCity} {!c.MailingCountry}
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!c.Account.Name}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Location (retrieved from DB or geocoded server-side)">
                        {!c.Location__Latitude__s}, {!c.Location__Longitude__s}
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="mapSection">
                    <div id="map_canvas" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
               <apex:pageBlockSection title="Click to show/hide what was geocoded server-side and passed to JS for further manipulation" columns="1" id="debugSection">
                    <pre>{!debugContactsJson}</pre>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <pre id="log"></pre>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        twistSection(document.getElementById('page:form:resultsBlock:debugSection').childNodes[0].childNodes[0]); // initially hide the debug section

        var con = {!contactsJson};    // Array of contact data, some of them might have lat/long info, some we'll have to geocode client side
        var coords = [];                   // Just the latitude/longitude for each contact
        var requestCounter = 0;

        var markers = [];                  // Red things we pin to the map.
        var balloon = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // Comic-like baloon that floats over markers.
          alert(con.length);
        function geocodeClientSide() {
            for(var i = 0; i < con.length; i++) {
                if(con[i].Location__Latitude__s != null && con[i].Location__Longitude__s != null) {
                    coords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(con[i].Location__Latitude__s, con[i].Location__Longitude__s));

                } else {
                    ++requestCounter;
                    var address = con[i].Location__Latitude__s + ' ' + con[i].Location__Longitude__s;
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    if (geocoder) {
                        geocoder.geocode({'address':address}, function (results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                coords.push(results[0].geometry.location);
                            } else {
                                var pTag = document.createElement("p");
                                pTag.innerHTML = status;
                                document.getElementById('log').appendChild(pTag);
                            }
                            if(--requestCounter == 0) {
                                drawMap();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            // It could be the case that all was geocoded on server side (or simply retrieved from database).
            // So if we're lucky - just proceed to drawing the map.
            if(requestCounter == 0) {
                drawMap();
            }
        }

        function drawMap(){
            var mapOptions = {
                center: coords[0],
                zoom: 3,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),  mapOptions);
            for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; ++i){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: coords[i], title:con[i].Name, zIndex:i});   

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                  return function () {
                  var index = this.zIndex;
                    balloon.setContent('<b>'+con[index].Name + '</b><br/>' + con[index].Account.Name + '<br/>' + con[index].Email);
                    balloon.open(map, marker);
                    }
                  })(marker, i));

                markers.push(marker);
            }
        }
       geocodeClientSide();
        </script>
    </apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public with sharing class mapController{
public String searchText {get;set;}
public List<Contact> contacts{get; private set;}
public List<Account> acc{get; private set;}
public List<lead> lea{get; private set;}
public list<list<sObject>> Results {get;set;}
Public list<sobject> sobjlst{get;set;}
public list<Account> objAccounts {get;set;}
public static final String GEOCODING_URI_BASE = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=';

// For purposes of this demo I'll geocode only couple of addresses server-side. Real code can use the commented out value.
public static final Integer MAX_CALLOUTS_FROM_APEX = 100000; // Limits.getLimitCallouts();

public mapController(){

}

//public List<sObject> sobjlst {get; set;}
public void find() {
    if(searchText != null && searchText.length() > 1){
        List<List<SObject>> results = [FIND :('*' + searchText + '*') IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
            Contact (Id, Name, Email, Account.Name,MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingPostalCode, MailingState, MailingCountry,Location__Latitude__s, Location__Longitude__s) ,
            Account (Id, Name, Billingstreet, Billingcity, BillingPostalcode, Billingstate, Billingcountry,Location__Latitude__s,Location__Longitude__s) ,
            Lead (Id, Name, Email, street,city,postalcode,state,country,Location__Latitude__s,Location__Longitude__s)
            ];
        contacts = (List<Contact>)results[0];
        acc=(List<account>)results[1];
        lea=(List<lead>)results[2];
         sobjlst = new List<sObject>();
         for(list<sObject> objectList :results ){
            sobjlst .addall(objectList);
           }

        if(sobjlst.isEmpty()){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'No matches for "' + searchText + '"'));
        } else {
            serverSideGeocode();
        }
    } else {
        if(sobjlst != null) {
            contacts.clear();
        }
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Please provide at least 2 characters for the search.'));
    }
}

public void clearGeocodedData(){
    for(Contact c : contacts){
        c.Location__Latitude__s = c.Location__Longitude__s = null;
    }
    Database.update(contacts, false);
    contacts.clear();
}

public String getContactsJson(){
    return JSON.serialize(sobjlst);
}
public String getDebugContactsJson(){
    return JSON.serializePretty(sobjlst);
}

private void serverSideGeocode(){
    List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    List<account> accountsToupdate = new List<Account>();
    List<lead> leadsToupdate = new List<Lead>();
    Http h = new Http();  
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET'); 
    req.setTimeout(10000);

    for(Contact c : contacts){
        if((c.Location__Latitude__s == null || c.Location__Longitude__s == null)){
            String address = c.MailingStreet != null ? c.MailingStreet + ' ' : '' +
                c.MailingCity != null ? c.MailingCity + ' ' : '' +
                c.MailingState != null ? c.MailingState + ' ' : '' +
                c.MailingPostalCode != null ? c.MailingPostalCode + ' ' : '' +
                c.MailingCountry != null ? c.MailingCountry : '';
            if(address != ''){
                req.setEndpoint(GEOCODING_URI_BASE + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(address, 'UTF-8'));
                try{
                    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
                    GResponse gr = (GResponse) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), mapController.GResponse.class);
                    if(gr.status == 'OK'){
                        LatLng ll = gr.results[0].geometry.location;
                        c.Location__Latitude__s = ll.lat;
                        c.Location__Longitude__s = ll.lng;
                        contactsToUpdate.add(c);
                    } else {
                        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Geocoding of "' + address + '" failed:' + gr.status));
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    ApexPages.addMessages(e);
                }
            }
            // Bail out if we've reached limit of callouts (not all contacts might have been processed).
            if(Limits.getCallouts() == MAX_CALLOUTS_FROM_APEX) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

        for(account a : acc){
        if((a.Location__Latitude__s == null || a.Location__Longitude__s == null)){
            String address = a.BillingStreet != null ? a.billingStreet + ' ' : '' +
                a.billingCity != null ? a.billingCity + ' ' : '' +
                a.billingState != null ? a.billingState + ' ' : '' +
                a.billingPostalCode != null ? a.billingPostalCode + ' ' : '' +
                a.billingCountry != null ? a.billingCountry : '';
            if(address != ''){
                req.setEndpoint(GEOCODING_URI_BASE + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(address, 'UTF-8'));
                try{
                    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
                    GResponse gr = (GResponse) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), mapController.GResponse.class);
                    if(gr.status == 'OK'){
                        LatLng ll = gr.results[1].geometry.location;
                        a.Location__Latitude__s = ll.lat;
                        a.Location__Longitude__s = ll.lng;
                        accountsToUpdate.add(a);
                    } else {
                        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Geocoding of "' + address + '" failed:' + gr.status));
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    ApexPages.addMessages(e);
                }
            }
            // Bail out if we've reached limit of callouts (not all contacts might have been processed).
            if(Limits.getCallouts() == MAX_CALLOUTS_FROM_APEX) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

        for(lead l : lea){
        if((l.Location__Latitude__s == null || l.Location__Longitude__s == null)){
            String address = l.Street != null ? l.Street + ' ' : '' +
               l.City != null ? l.City + ' ' : '' +
                l.State != null ? l.State + ' ' : '' +
                l.PostalCode != null ? l.PostalCode + ' ' : '' +
                l.Country != null ? l.Country : '';
            if(address != ''){
                req.setEndpoint(GEOCODING_URI_BASE + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(address, 'UTF-8'));
                try{
                    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
                    GResponse gr = (GResponse) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), mapController.GResponse.class);
                    if(gr.status == 'OK'){
                        LatLng ll = gr.results[2].geometry.location;
                        l.Location__Latitude__s = ll.lat;
                        l.Location__Longitude__s = ll.lng;
                        leadsToUpdate.add(l);
                    } else {
                        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Geocoding of "' + address + '" failed:' + gr.status));
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    ApexPages.addMessages(e);
                }
            }
            // Bail out if we've reached limit of callouts (not all contacts might have been processed).
            if(Limits.getCallouts() == MAX_CALLOUTS_FROM_APEX) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!contactsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
        Database.update(contactsToUpdate, false); // some data in Developer editions is invalid (on purpose I think).
        // If update fails because "j.davis@expressl&amp;t.net" is not a valid Email, I want the rest to succeed
    }
        if(!AccountsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
        Database.update(AccountsToUpdate, false); // some data in Developer editions is invalid (on purpose I think).
        // If update fails because "j.davis@expressl&amp;t.net" is not a valid Email, I want the rest to succeed
    }
        if(!leadsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
        Database.update(leadsToUpdate, false); // some data in Developer editions is invalid (on purpose I think).
        // If update fails because "j.davis@expressl&amp;t.net" is not a valid Email, I want the rest to succeed
    }
}

// Helper class - template into which results of lookup will be parsed. Some fields are skipped!
// Visit https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Results if you need to create full mapping.
public class GResponse{
    public String status;
    public GComponents[] results;
}
public class GComponents{
   public String formatted_address;
   public GGeometry geometry;
}
public class GGeometry {
    public LatLng location;
}
public class LatLng{
    public Double lat, lng;
}
}
```

There is a text box to enter Area Based on that it has to show near leads and contacts

I am getting two errors first of all it is showing only contacts ,second thing is i am getting error "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"

I am sending all object data coordinates into jsonstring "ContactsJson" .But in map it is taking only contacts info ?

Comment: [OVER_QUERY_LIMIT](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits) is a error code related with Google maps API. It usually means that you have exceeded the usage limits or are issuing more number of queries per minute than allowed.

Comment: @manjit_singh I cant locate all accounts leads only contacts it is showing